# How to get enabled configurable products which has associate products without inventory? [Magento 2]

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento-enterprise, magento-community

My Query is: I want to get enabled configurable products which has associate products without inventory OR child products of enabled config products have inventory zero.

> **Use below code for filter out of stock Simple/Config products** ***[magento 2 out of stock enabled configurable products]***

```
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');

$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create();

$collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);

$collection =
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
->joinField('qty',
        'cataloginventory_stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    )->joinTable('cataloginventory_stock_item', 'product_id=entity_id', ['stock_status' => 'is_in_stock'])
    ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
    ->addFieldToFilter('stock_status', ['eq' => 0])
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', ['eq' => 'configurable'])->load();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo 'Config Product SKU: '.$product->getSku()."\n\n";
}
```

> **Note:** Change **$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', ['eq' => 'configurable'])** as per your requirements.

> **MySQL Query as follows:**

SELECT `e`.*, `at_qty`.`qty`, `cataloginventory_stock_item`.`is_in_stock` AS `stock_status`, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.stock_id=1)
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` ON (cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id=e.entity_id)
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '94') AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '94') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 14) WHERE ((cataloginventory_stock_item.is_in_stock = 0) AND (IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = '1') AND (`e`.`type_id` = 'configurable')) AND (e.created_in <= '1589313000') AND (e.updated_in > '1589313000') ORDER BY `e`.`created_at` DESC;